# information about tiff image

Tags: matlab

`iminfo` of my image gives

> FormatSignature: [73 73 42 0]

`Offset: 264322`
what is an offset?how this value comes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the signature of a TIFF file. Matlab's way of saying "I endorse this file as TIFF".

Matlab detects the file type by itself, not from the extension. Change the extension to JPG or XYZ, you'll still open it as a TIFF file.

Edit: 
This is for PNG for example :
137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10
GIF:
71 73 70 56 57 97 16 0

You can also use an hex editor, open the file, grab the first 8 bytes and convert it from hex to decimal.

Comment: wat's the significance of the number 73 73 40 0

Comment: Those are just numbers, nothing significant. It is the standart of the TIFF file. (73 73 40 0 is in HEX 49 49 2A 00). They could have choosen 80 80 10 10, but they used these. Most files use the first 8 bytes to keep the "what i am" information, so the applications can detect them even though the file extension is different.

Comment: do u know wat's the value of offset?

Comment: Offset is mostly the data packet in the file. The packet may include information about the file size, type (like a true color image), author information, pixel information, etc. For TIFF format I don't know what offsets include, as this requires the know-how of the file format. But [here is a documentation of the TIFF](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf) if you want to dig deeper. I assume you are trying to build a multipage TIFF reader?